# nginx 502 bad gateway gunicorn

Tags: django, python-2.7, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to load a page with django formset, I can clearly see in the logs that the backend logic is executed well within 1 second, I have a logger printing right before return render() and it is very clear that the backend process is almost done. The point is that,it is taking way too much time to render the template and nginx throwing bad gateway at me. What should I do?

Comment: What do the nginx logs say?

Comment: 2017/12/28 13:26:57 [error] 1535#1535: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.2.2, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "localhost:8000"

Comment: 2017/12/28 14:14:41 [error] 1534#1534: *16 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.2.2, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /academics/subjects-to-teacher/add HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/academics/subjects-to-teacher/add", host: "localhost:8000", referrer: "http://localhost:8000/empty"

Comment: @EvansMurithi this is what I could find.

Comment: In my django template I have a formset tag to render html, strangely when I remove the tag page loads all normal. Anyone know why that happens?